# Enable/disable a Java swing button in relation with a combo box

Tags: java, swing

How can I update the state (enable/disable) of my button when the user changes the selected item in a combo box.?

The button has a reference to the combo box, but the combo box does not know anything about the button.

Comment: it's bad practice to couple views (aka: let the button have a reference to the combo). Instead, use an Action set to the JButton to decouple: the listener to the comboBox selection changes knows that Action and toggles its enablement as appropriate. Internals care about updating the button accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the button has a reference to the combo box, then the button can register an action listener at the combo box in which you can change the state of your button.

```
final JButton button = new JButton();
final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();

comboBox.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed( final ActionEvent event ) {
        // Your logic to determine when to enable/disable:
        final boolean enabled = comboBox.getSelectedIndex() == 0;
        button.setEnabled( enabled );
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thanks its work. 
@Kleopatra
It is surely a bad practice to couple views, but i have not the choice, i want my button to also listen a Jtable, so i cannot define it inside the Tollbar's class

Comment: @user1722605 sure you have a choice ... you simply insist on doing it the bad way ;-) The more (view) collaborators are involved, the more important to decouple.

Answer (score 2):

The combobox is not required to know about the button. You need to add a listener to the combobox events like this:

```
public class ComboBoxDemo ... implements ActionListener {
. . .
    petList.addActionListener(this) {
. . .
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
    String petName = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
    yourButton.setEnabled(true/false);
}
. . .
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The `JButton` could simply add its own `ActionListener` on the `JComboBox` and in the `ActionListener` you could then change the state of the `JButton` according to the selected item of the combo box.

Answer (score 1):

I have previously written code where enabling or disabling a button depends on filling a textfield and selecting an item of a combobox together. It may be helpful here.

```
jComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jComboBoxActionPerformed(e);
            }
        });
...
jTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                jTextFieldDocumentListener(e);
            }
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                jTextFieldDocumentListener(e);
            }
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                jTextFieldDocumentListener(e);
            }
        });
        jTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jTextFieldActionPerformed(e);
            }
        });
...

private void jComboBoxActionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(jComboBox.getSelectedIndex() == -1)
            jButton.setEnabled(false);
        else if(!jTextField.getText().equals(""))
            jButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
private void jTextFieldDocumentListener(DocumentEvent e){
        if(jTextField.getText().equals("") || jComboBox.getSelectedIndex() == -1){
            jButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else{
            jButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private void jTextFieldActionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        if(jTextField.getText().equals("")){
            jButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if(!(jTextField.getText().equals(""))){
            jButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

If the combobox is selected and the textfield is filled, then the button will be enabled. Otherwise it will not be enabled.